# 複数端末間で履歴を共有する機能を持っているシェルは？

Tags: shell

複数端末を同時に開いても、履歴を正しく取り扱えるシェルにはどのようなものがありますか。

tmux を使い始めて、この場合でも履歴を正しく取り扱いたくなったことと、 [bash でも実現できるみたい](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/sppr/20090109/1231518070) ですが、ちょっと力技すぎると感じたために質問しています。

Comment: [Korn shell](http://www.kornshell.com/) はデフォルトでヒストリを共有します。Linux 系 distribution では `ksh` パッケージとして提供されていて、中身は `AT&T Korn shell` の 1993 年版の様です。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

zsh では `setopt share_history` すると、複数起動したシェル間で履歴を共有します。