# プログラムから zsh の歴史を追加するには？

Tags: zsh

emacs の中で実行する shell-command も、 zsh の歴史に記録したいと思いました。
そのためには、プログラムから履歴を操作できれば、これが実現できると思っているのですが、これをどう実現するかがわかりません。

[複数端末間で履歴を共有する機能を持っているシェルは？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/24309/754) にあるように、 zsh では複数セッション間でも履歴を共有する機能もあるので、適切な built-in なコマンドがあって、それで編集することになるのであろうとは思っているのですが。。

質問:

- プログラムから zsh の歴史を追加する方法はありますか？

Answer (score 1):

`print -s`とか。

```
% print -s echo hello
% history -1
10368  echo hello
```

Comment: interactive シェルからこれを実行すると、たしかに履歴に追加されたのですが、シェルスクリプトの中から実行しても、履歴に追加されず。。